# ORA-02248 while trying to set NLS_CALENDAR from a PL/SQL procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a need to change the session's `NLS_CALENDAR` parameter using a PL/SQL procedure (Note: it is a constraint in the application I am working that I must use a procedure).

I am trying to do this:

```
-- this procedure is a part of pl/sql package Test_Pkg
PROCEDURE Set_Nls_Calendar(calendar_ IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
      'ALTER SESSION
      SET NLS_CALENDAR = :cal'
      USING IN calendar_;
END Set_Nls_Calendar;
```

Then in the client side, I am trying to invoke the procedure:

```
Test_Pkg.Set_Nls_Calendar('Thai Buddha');
```

But this get's me `ORA-02248: invalid option for ALTER SESSION`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use bind variables in DDL statements, only in some parts of DML statements. At the moment `:cal` is being seen as an identifier, not a bind, so you're trying to do:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_CALENDAR = :cal
```

... which would give the same error as `:cal` isn't a valid option. The `calendar_` value isn't being used at all.

You have to concatenate the value, while enclosing it in quotes:

```
PROCEDURE Set_Nls_Calendar(calendar_ IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
      'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_CALENDAR = ''' || calendar_ || '''';
END Set_Nls_Calendar;
```

Comment: That worked. I did not know that I **can't use bind variables in DDL statements**. Thanks, I learned something.

Comment: [Why cannot I use bind variables in DDL/SCL statements in dynamic SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25489002/why-cannot-i-use-bind-variables-in-ddl-scl-statements-in-dynamic-sql)